# How can I retrieve only the record related to the last value of a date field in this specific case using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I am finding some problem trying to modify a query defined on MySql.

I have this query that is my starting poing (the query that have to be modified):

```
SELECT
    MC_PS.id                                            AS price_series_id,
    MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id                   AS market_commodity_details_id,
    MC_PS.price_date                                    AS price_date,
    MC_PS.avg_price                                     AS avg_price,
    CU.ISO_4217_cod                                     AS currency,
    MU.unit_name                                        AS measure_unit,
    MD_CD.market_details_id                             AS market_id,
    MD_CD.commodity_details_id                          AS commodity_id

    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MC_PS

    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
        ON MC_PS.measure_unit_id = MU.id

    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU
        ON MC_PS.currency_id = CU.id

    INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD
          ON MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id
```

This query returns the prices of some commodities in some market, this is the query output:

```
price_series_id      market_commodity_details_id price_date      avg_price            currency measure_unit       market_id            commodity_id        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17                   25                          18/12/2017      778                  RWF      kilogram           4                    6                   
70                   32                          17/12/2017      5                    RWF      kilogram           6                    16                  
71                   32                          18/12/2017      6                    RWF      kilogram           6                    16                  
3                    26                          15/12/2017      12,84                XOF      kilogram           4                    8                   
4                    25                          15/12/2017      18,233               XOF      kilogram           4                    6                   
5                    25                          16/12/2017      22,84                XOF      kilogram           4                    6                   
6                    24                          16/12/2017      18,94                XOF      kilogram           4                    4                   
7                    24                          17/12/2017      28,63                XOF      kilogram           4                    4                   
9                    26                          18/12/2017      48,37                XOF      kilogram           4                    8                   
11                   24                          18/12/2017      33,33                XOF      kilogram           4                    4                   
18                   28                          18/12/2017      13,7                 XOF      kilogram           5                    4                   
19                   28                          17/12/2017      16,2                 XOF      kilogram           5                    4                   
20                   28                          16/12/2017      14,9                 XOF      kilogram           5                    4                   
21                   30                          18/12/2017      21,47                XOF      kilogram           5                    3                   
22                   30                          16/12/2017      22,39                XOF      kilogram           5                    3                   
23                   30                          17/12/2017      23,17                XOF      kilogram           5                    3                   
24                   26                          17/12/2017      16,22                XOF      kilogram           4                    8                   
26                   26                          16/12/2017      19,39                XOF      kilogram           4                    8                   
27                   31                          18/12/2017      13,2                 XOF      kilogram           5                    8                   
28                   31                          17/12/2017      14,4                 XOF      kilogram           5                    8                   
29                   31                          16/12/2017      12,6                 XOF      kilogram           5                    8                   
31                   25                          17/12/2017      17,8                 XOF      kilogram           4                    6                   
32                   25                          17/12/2017      14,8                 XOF      kilogram           4                    6                   
33                   29                          18/12/2017      8,2                  XOF      kilogram           5                    1                   
34                   29                          17/12/2017      9,6                  XOF      kilogram           5                    1                   
35                   29                          16/12/2017      9,3                  XOF      kilogram           5                    1
```

As you can see it contains the price of a commodity (**commodity_id**) sold into a market (**market_id**) in a specific day (**price_date**).

I need to modify my query in such a way that show only the last price of a commodity sold in a market.

Practically if in the previous result there are multiple record related to a specific commodity sold in a specific market related different dates, have to be returned a single record for the last date.

So the output of my modified query have to be something like this one:

```
price_series_id      market_commodity_details_id price_date      avg_price            currency measure_unit       market_id            commodity_id        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
71                   32                          18/12/2017      6                    RWF      kilogram           6                    16                                  
9                    26                          18/12/2017      48,37                XOF      kilogram           4                    8                  
11                   24                          18/12/2017      33,33                XOF      kilogram           4                    4                 
18                   28                          18/12/2017      13,7                 XOF      kilogram           5                    4                                    
21                   30                          18/12/2017      21,47                XOF      kilogram           5                    3                                                    
27                   31                          18/12/2017      13,2                 XOF      kilogram           5                    8                                 
17                   25                          18/12/2017      778                  RWF      kilogram           4                    6                  
33                   29                          18/12/2017      8,2                  XOF      kilogram           5                    1
```

As you can see for each **market_id** and **commodity_id** fields are retrieved only the records related to the last **price_date** value

How can I correctly implement this change?

Maybe can I use a **GROUP BY** used with an **HAVING** clause in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `Market_Commodity_Price_Series`  table have an autoincrementing `id` column?  Does your application always `INSERT` new rows with recent `price_date` values into it?

If so, you can add a WHERE clause to your query as follows

```
WHERE MC_PS.id IN  ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
                       FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
                      GROUP BY market_commodity_details_id )
```

This will filter  out all but the highest `id` value for each item. If the assumptions are true, that will also be the latest value.

IF those assumptions do not hold true, you can use a similar kind of filter but it's harder.  To get the latest `id` value for each item you do this:

```
           SELECT a.id
             FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series a
             JOIN (
                     SELECT MAX(price_date) price_date,
                            market_commodity_details_id 
                       FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series 
                      GROUP BY market_commodity_details_id 
                  ) b ON a.market_commodity_details_id = b.market_commodity_details_id 
                     AND a.price_date = b.price_date
```

This query looks at your table and finds the latest date for each item. It then recovers the `id` value of that item. You can then use that whole subquery in a `WHERE id IN ()` clause like the one shown above.

Comment: I changed my downvote to an upvote. Use O Jones second solution. The 1st one is not a good idea imho

Comment: If the preconditions hold (autoincrementing ID, no UPDATEs, only INSERTs, and every insert using the current date, my first solution is correct and performs very well indeed, opinions to the contrary notwithstanding.  It also correctly disambiguates duplicate latest-date values if there are multiples.

Answer (score 0):

O. Jones's 1st idea is not a good one. Use a subquery to get the record with latest date and join to that. This is untested but look at the last join

```
SELECT
    MC_PS.id                                            AS price_series_id,
    MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id                   AS     market_commodity_details_id,
    MC_PS.price_date                                    AS price_date,
    MC_PS.avg_price                                     AS avg_price,
    CU.ISO_4217_cod                                     AS currency,
    MU.unit_name                                        AS measure_unit,
    MD_CD.market_details_id                             AS market_id,
    MD_CD.commodity_details_id                          AS commodity_id

FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MC_PS

INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON MC_PS.measure_unit_id = MU.id

INNER JOIN Currency AS CU
    ON MC_PS.currency_id = CU.id

INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD
      ON MC_PS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id , MAX(price_date) as price_date
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series 
    GROUP BY id) b on MC_PS.id = b.id AND MC_PS.price_date = b.price_date
```